# Django BinaryField retrieved as memory position?

Tags: python, django, database, python-3.x, binary

I've written a short unit test with the following code:

```
my_object = MyObject()
my_object.data = b'12345'

my_object.save()
saved_object = MyObject.objects.first()

assert saved_object.data == my_object.data
```

where `MyObject` is defined as:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    data = models.BinaryField(default=None)
```

I would expect the assert to pass, as I'm just saving some byte data and then retrieving it. However, I end up with:

```
AssertionError: assert <memory at 0x10e2abc48> == b'12345'
```

I'm guessing that it has to do with directly saving the byte string to the binary field. On the other hand, it seems strange that the save succeeds at all then. And I'm having a bit of difficultly finding some good example uses of Django's `BinaryField`. Can anyone explain to me what's happening here or what I'm doing wrong? Thank you much.

Comment: Also see [Django ticket 27813](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27813)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Django normalizes the content of the `BinaryField` to a buffer. In Python2 to [`buffer`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#buffer) and [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) in Python3 to be specific.

You can see that in source code:

- `to_python` [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2390)
- `six.memoryview` [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/six.py#L873-L883)

In Python2 `buffer` does not implement comparison logic which is why your assertion fails:

```
Python 2.7.11
>>> m = buffer(b'hello')
>>> m == b'hello'
False
>>> bytes(m) == b'hello'
True
```

However it does implement other operations such as slicing and length:

```
>>> len(m)
5
>>> m[1:]
'ello'
```

In Python 3 the story is much better since it implements all expected operations:

```
Python 3.5.1
>>> m = memoryview(b'hello')
>>> m
<memory at 0x109e8b108>
>>> bytes(m)
b'hello'
>>> m == b'hello'
True
>>> bytes(m) == b'hello'
True
>>> len(m)
5
>>> m[1:]
<memory at 0x109e8b1c8>
```

Im not sure the reason why Django does that however my guess would be for efficiency. Buffers are much more efficient at handling memory. For example when you slice, it can reuse the same memory vs allocating more memory.

Comment: This certainly explains the problem and a way how to fix it. However, there's one other thing. If I alter my code to use `assert bytes(saved_object.data) == my_object.data`, then the test passes. I'm using Python 3 and your example runs as you stated. However, the direct comparison with the memoryview to the byte data still fails when put through the Django save and retrieve test. It's not super important, but do you happen to know why the memoryview *must* be converted back to bytes in that case for the comparison to work, but not for the case without Django?

Comment: which Python3 version?

Comment: 3.5.0 (the same one I'm using to run your above example, which works as you stated). Django version 1.8.

Comment: hmm. dont know. from the error message it looks like you use pytest. maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: I thought it might be too, so I converted your example code into a test form and tried running it with pytest. The test passed in that case, so it appears to be something else. In any case, just forcing the memoryview into bytes works well enough for my case. So thank you for that and the understanding behind it.