# Issues with printing bytea data from PostgreSQL in python, but always get <memory at 0x> address

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So I am having some troubles getting access the `bytea` binary data from PostgreSQL using Python. So this is the model for `Images`:

```
class Images(models.Model):
    image_code = models.BinaryField()
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='IMG_CAPTION')
```

Here is the data table from PostgreSQL

| id | image_code (bytea) | caption (char var) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [binary] | DEFAULT CAPTION |

So in my project I have following

```
store_length = len(Images.objects.all())
image_shown = Images.objects.all()[store_length-1]
code_string = image_shown.image_code
print(code_string.image_code)
```

The output I get is memory address `<memory at 0x7ff5ae03a888>`. The output is supposed to be string.

What should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is described in [Django ticket 27813](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27813).

The ticket mentions how [Django's test suite works around this issue](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.1.x/tests/model_fields/test_binaryfield.py#L22) by explicitly casting to `bytes`.

So, in the OP's example, that would be:

```py
...
print(bytes(image_shown.image_code))
```

If you want string output, call [bytes.decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode).

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254866